# Scout Eclipse Neon margin on fields

Tags: user-interface, field, margins, eclipse-scout

Is it possible to set a margin around fields.

For example in image :

[image: Current screenshot]

If I want to set lower (separated) checkBox in line with above once, is there a way to do it?

[image: Desired screenshot]

Marko

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve. Can you not post an example (wireframe, a screenshot modifed with Paint, ...) ?

Comment: I want to achieved that lower square (Unknown) will be aligned with others squares in ListBox (Driver, Contact person,...)

Comment: I think now I got it... I added a screenshot (3 Minutes work with Microsoft Paint). I recommend you to always ask detailed question if you want good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by inspecting the HTML code (with Chrome).

[image: Inspect Scout Field with Chrome]

The code corresponding to the Checkbox Field is something like that:

```
  <div class="form-field check-box-field" 
      data-modelclass="org.eclipse.scout.widgets.client.ui.forms.CheckboxFieldForm$MainBox$ConfigurationBox$CheckboxField"
      data-classid="CheckboxField_org.eclipse.scout.widgets.client.ui.forms.CheckboxFieldForm"
      id="scout.CheckBoxField[1-49]" 
      style="left: 0px; top: 14px; width: 1598px; height: 30px;"
    >
    <div class="field has-inner-alignment halign-left valign-top" style=
    "left: 148px; top: 0px; width: 1420px; height: 30px;">
      <div class="check-box" tabindex="0"></div>
      <div class="label">
        Checkbox
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

With CSS you can do anything possible:

```
.check-box-field {
    background-color: red;
}
```

[image: Scout CheckBox Red Background]

Now because you do not want to add some custom CSS style for all CheckBox Fields, you can define a custom Css-Class in your CheckBox:

```
  @Order(4)
  public class UnknownCheckBox extends AbstractBooleanField {

    @Override
    protected String getConfiguredCssClass() {
      return "checkbox-under-listbox";
    }
    // ... Some Code ...
  }
```

And now you add this CSS code:

```
.checkbox-under-listbox {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

---

I have realized this example with the Widgets Demo Application ([org.eclipse.scout.docs repository, releases/5.2.x branch](https://github.com/BSI-Business-Systems-Integration-AG/org.eclipse.scout.docs/tree/releases/5.2.x)). I added my css code in this file: `org.eclipse.scout.widgets.ui.html/src/main/js/widgets/main.css` (It is probably not the best approach to have everything in `main.css`).

You can deduce from this example how you can add an additional CSS/LESS module and macro to your application. This post: [Inclusion of additional icons from font-awesome](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1074535&goto=1722703&#msg_1722703) might also be usefull. You will have a `main.css` instead of a `font.css`.

---

**WARNING:** this is not state of the art.

*At the end this is normal HTML development (single page application of course), so you can do what you want...*

If you do not want to use the LESS compiler and the File preprocessor, you can simpelly add a normal CSS file in the folder:

```
<your_project>.ui.html/src/main/resources/WebContent
```

Let say:

```
<your_project>.ui.html/src/main/resources/WebContent/my_custom.css
```

Do not forget to include your CSS File between the `<head>` and `</head>` tags in the HTML index file:

```
<your_project>.ui.html/src/main/resources/WebContent/index.html
```

Something like:

```
<head>
  <!-- some code -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my_custom.css">
  <scout:stylesheet src="res/scout-module.css" />
  <!-- some code -->
</head>
```

Comment: Hi, I found your answer really good, but I have one small problem. I don't have ...ui.htmi/src/main/js folder... do I need exact this folder or could be .css file be elsewhere? I try with ..ui.html/src/main/resources/WebContent/res where all-macro.css is. I add new .css file and I add @include("main.scc") into the all-macro.css file, but it still don't work.

Comment: I make typo : @include("main.css"), still don't work.

Comment: Create the `...ui.html/src/main/js` folder if requested. In the [module file](https://github.com/BSI-Business-Systems-Integration-AG/org.eclipse.scout.docs/blob/releases/5.2.x/code/widgets/org.eclipse.scout.widgets.ui.html/src/main/js/widgets-module.css) it is `//@include("main.css")`. In the [macro file](https://github.com/BSI-Business-Systems-Integration-AG/org.eclipse.scout.docs/blob/releases/5.2.x/code/widgets/org.eclipse.scout.widgets.ui.html/src/main/resources/WebContent/res/widgets-all-macro.css) the same. You need your build to be correctly configured.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use custom CSS: Let your field implement `IStyleable` and use `setCssClass()` to apply an appropriate CSS class. I'd try to avoid using such pixel pushing approaches as much as possible.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, but there is no documentation of what kind of string need to be created in this method. Could you present some example...

Comment: I try : cssClass = "{margin-left: 80px;}"; but it doesn't work

Comment: It's just the name of the CSS class. The class itself must be defined in your CSS file.

Comment: Thenks, but where do I found this class in NEON scout?

Comment: The answer of Jmini is much more comprehensive. Thank you, @jmini.